# How do I send DM to all users in list with discord.py with defined function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

been building a discord.py bot for some time for a community im in. Currently I am working on a "mailing list" of sorts where if I run spesific commands the bot sends a message to everyone on a (currently) hardcoded list.

Here is my code.

```
#imports
import discord
import json

#takes token form config
with open("./config.json") as config:
  configData = json.load(config)
token = configData["Token"]

#discord intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

#login
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

list = ["12345678910","111213141516171819"]

#defining dm function
def dm_function():
  for user in list:
    user.send("test")


#makes and sends an embed to the channel command was used in and send the dm:s
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!testing'):
      #embed stuff
      

#logins to bot with config.json
client.run(token)
```

Instead of sending anything in the dm, the dm:s remain empty. (The bot only sends the embed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list of IDs, get the user object and use the `send` method.

- [client docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user)
- [user docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.send)

```py
user_list = ["12345678910","111213141516171819"]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!testing'):
        for user_id in user_list:
            user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
            try:
                await user.send("Here's a DM")
            except discord.Forbidden:
                # don't have permissions to send them a DM
                continue
```

I have also renamed your `list` variable. It is bad practice to name a variable after an existing python type.